# Bin packing (NP-Complete)

Tags: complexity-theory, machine-learning

I'm working on a project over Bin packing being NP complete, I understand the full reasoning behind it (algorithmically), but I need to know what's a proper explanation for the Bin packing being NP complete (the computational way "theory of computation") not algortihmically.

Comment: You should be able to see the similarity to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

Comment: There's nothing regarding Bin Packing in there

Comment: Justin, it’s in there quite obviously. Given items with total size of 20,000, can you split them into two groups with total size 10,000 each? Given items with total size 20,000 and bins of size 10,000, can you fit them into two bins or do you need three bins?